# The pond of symmetry

Tags: mathematics, geometry

There is a $4$m by $4$m square pond. You have $3$ straight planks of wood, each exactly $2$m in length.

You need to place the planks so that they go from one corner of the pond to the diagonally opposite one. There is to be no plank overlapping.

The planks must be laid rotationally symmetric around the centre of the pond.

> How do you do it, using only a water-compass? (i.e. no angle-ommeters!)

Comment: What do you mean by "water-compass" exactly?

Comment: @Deusovi; as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction, but for use in water.

Comment: Do we also not have any form of straightedge? Can we assume that our weight is negligible in comparison to the weight of the planks of wood? (that is, that we can walk on the planks of wood without worrying about them tipping and falling in?) Can the compass be used *on* the planks of wood, separately from the water?

Comment: walking around the pond isn't an option?

Comment: The planks are straight-edged. You only need to place the planks - you can swim in the pond if you want.

Comment: Does the "water-compass" make marks on the water that stay there?

Comment: No. It uses light-weight lasers that show an exact mark on the surface. @Deusovi

Comment: Do the planks have 0 width?

Comment: @Jens; yes, but they also have infinite density so that they sink.

Comment: @SteveV, I was thinking the same XD

Comment: This water business seems very complicated. Are you just asking us to use a pair of compasses to construct three length-2 line segments laid edge to edge from one corner of a 4×4 square to another such that the whole design has 180° rotational symmetry at the end?

Comment: You say the planks sink; does that mean they don't float? If so, is that relevant to the question? And do we only have one compass?

Answer (score 7):

Of course, the compass can be set to a radius of 2m, using a plank. Similarly with 1m - if you disagree, use the compass to mark 1/2 of a plank.

First, to find the center,

> Use a plank to find the midpoint of one side, and use the water compass to construct a line through that point and perpendicular to the side. Again using a plank of 2m gives the center. Use your watercolor pencil to mark it. [image]

Then, to position all three planks,

> make circles of radius 2m around two opposing cornes, and a circle of radius 1m around the center: [image]

Comment: "Watercolor pencil"! Always handy.

Answer (score 1):

[image: circ]

Let's have a square pond where AB=AC=4. First we draw the diagonal AD. From point A we draw a circumference with R1=2. From the point where the circumference cuts the diagonal AD we draw a circle with R2=2. Finally, from the point D we draw another circle with R3=2. We set points where R1 cuts the diagonal AD and where the circles with R2 and R3 intersect. We set the planks between A and the first point, between the two points, and from the second point to D.